# Render video using direct3D

Tags: c++, video, windows-store-apps, ms-media-foundation, direct3d11

We have an old application uisng DirectDraw 8. It writes pixel by pixel to video memory directly and everything is fine.
Now I need port it into a windows stores app.

Media Foundation seems to be the recommended path for rendering video and went through the "Media engine native C++ video playback sample (Windows 8.1)"
But even Media Foundation uses DirectDraw for the video rendering.

```
    ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> backBuffer; 
    DX11SwapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&backBuffer));

     m_spMediaEngine->TransferVideoFrame(backBuffer.Get(), nullptr, &m_rcTarget, &m_bkgColor);

     DX11SwapChain->Present(1, 0);
```

So went through the Direct3D samples and am able to get the backBuffer. But all the samples seem to be dealing with drawing lines etc.
and none on setting individual pixels.

How do I get my hands on the pixels? i.e set BackBuffer[somepixel] = someRGBA

Comment: Media Foundation does not use DirectDraw. Even for its predecessor, DirectShow, DirectDraw was an option only. Media Foundation uses Direct3D through EVR.

Comment: I appreciate the correction. I would be grateful if you could direct me to some pointers on how to write to the "backBuffer" (now called ID3D11Texture2D) in Direct3D like we did in DirectDraw days.

Answer (score 0):

UpdateSubresource worked fine for me. I could get about 60 FPS which was quite good.

```
    // get a pointer directly to the back buffer
    swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), &Backbuffer);

    // Width and Height
    swapchain->GetDesc1(&scd);
    Width = scd.Width;
    Height = scd.Height;

    TextureData = new UINT32[Width * Height];


void CMyClass::Render()
{
    UINT n, i;
    UINT  *psrc;
    psrc = TextureData;
    i = ScreenColourI & 255;
    ScreenColourI += 1;

    for (n=0; n<Width*Height; n++)
    {
        *psrc++ = (i<<16) | (i<<8) | i ;
        i++;
        i &= 255;
    }

    myID3D11DeviceContext->UpdateSubresource (Backbuffer.Get(), 0, NULL, TextureData, Width*4, 0);

    // switch the back buffer and the front buffer
    swapchain->Present(1, 0);

}
```